# Convert var to const javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to convert a var to a const?

Say in a scenario like this:

```
var appname = ''

function setAppName(name) {
   appname = name  // can I convert this to const now?
}
```

Basically, this is for a parameter level. Parameter needs to be accessible throughout the file and I want to make it const after first assignment.  Is this possible?

To add: If there is any other way besides creating an object with to contain this parameter, it would be better (for a more straightforward solution). I will be working on multiple parameters like this and freezing an object will cause the entire object to freeze. I am hoping to do this on the parameter level.

So either change the parameter to become const. OR (this one I dont think is possible) change the scope of the paramter to global:

```
function setAppName(name) {
   const appname = name  // can I change the scope and make this global?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your inputs.

I was able to find a workaround for what I was trying to achieve.

```
var appname = ''

function setAppName(name) {
  if (appname === '') {
    appname = name  // can I convert this to const now?
  }
}
```

Although this doesnt convert it to const, I just added a guard on the setter and it will not be able to overwrite the value now (unless otherwise I am going to initialize again to an empty string).

It is not fool-proof, but this will address my need.

Thanks all!

Comment: If you are placing these codes in browser, it would not work well. As you can always override `appname`, by having `var appname=''` later.

Answer (score 13):

Put your app name in an object and [freeze it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

```
let appSettings = { name: "" };
function setAppName(name) {
    appSettings.name = name;
    Object.freeze(appSettings);
}
```

Freezing prevents adding, removing and modifying the values of the properties in your object so you should call `Object.freeze` only once after all other settings (if there are more variables you want to make constant) have been set.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using a object.

```
const globals = {
    appname: ''
}

function setAppName(name) {
    globals.appname = name;
    Object.freeze(globals)
    // After this point, value of appname cannot be modified
}
```